# Identifying a value enclosed within other values in regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, windows

I have a string as follows:

```
<String>VariableText</String>
```

I need a regex to identify the "VariableText" value within the  node.

As the text suggests, the value could be variable.

How could this be achieved using regex?

Comment: In this particular example the regex is just `<String>(.+?)</String>` (or even `(?<=<String>).+?(?=</String>)`). But are you sure there's no other conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are two common regex patterns to get 'something' that's clearly delimited:

- using capturing groups:

`/%PatternForOpeningDelimiter%(.+?)%PatternForClosingDelimiter%/`

... or, in your case:

```
/<String>(.+?)<\/String>/
```

The content will be stored in `$1` variable.

- using lookarounds:

`/(?<=%PatternForOpeningDelimiter%).+?(?=%PatternForClosingDelimiter%)/`

... or, in your case:

```
/(?<=<String>).+?(?=<\/String>)/
```

This pattern will cover 'the required content', and there's no need to use regex variables (`$1`, `$2`, etc.)

Won't hurt to be aware, though, that variable-length patterns (such as `(?<=\d+)`, for example) can be used as look-behind expressions in .NET regex flavor (credits to @Alan Moore for that helpful observation), but many others lack this feature (or support it partially).

Comment: Actually, .NET is one of the extremely rare regex flavors that *do* let you put whatever you want in lookbehinds.

Answer (score 0):

i think this pattern could do what you want

```
string pattern =    "$<[s|S]tring>\w*</[s|S]tring>^";
Regex r= new Regex(pattern);
```

Comment: No, this will fail on `<String>Some Text</String>`.

Comment: string pattern =    "$<[s|S]tring>[^<]*</[s|S]tring>^";